# Function won't return JSON array

Tags: javascript, node.js, themoviedb-api

I have been pulling my hair out for the last day in hoping I can find a way of getting around or fixing this. I have tried everything I can think of, and no matter what, the function always returns `undefined`.

What I am trying to do is getting the information from [The Movie Database](https://www.themoviedb.org/), but via a function with a variable of the film's ID number. It retrieves the information perfectly, but the issue is, it won't return the JSON array. It always returns `undefined` and I'm unsure what is causing this.

```
 function getMovieData (movieid) {
    var data;

    moviedb.movieInfo({id: movieid}, (err, res) => {
        data = res; 
    })  

    return data;
}
```

The return value would be returned and would be used via Express and Handlebars to display to the user.

I am genuinely confused as to why this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems `movieInfo` is async function

Comment: I think you should return within the function.

`moviedb.movieInfo({id: movieid}, (err, res) => {
    return res; 
})` as its async.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that. But how would I get it to pass through the `movieid` value? I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do it.

Comment: Solved. Created another function which passes through the return data from the API call. The other function would set a variable which I could use in my view.